# Trigger Window Resize Event Listener from another Component - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have created two Components `Component1` and `Component2`. In the `Component1` I have registered window `resize` event (Whenever the page is resizing, it is getting triggered). I want to invoke this `resize` event from `Component2`.

Component1:

```
export default {
    name: 'Component1',
    async mounted() {
       window.addEventListener('resize', this.windowResize);
    },
    methods: {
       windowResize() {
          console.log("Window Resize event called")
       }
    }
};
```

Component2:

```
export default {
    name: 'Component2',
    methods: {
       doResize() {
         // Need to invoke Component1 Resize from here
       }
    }
};
```

**Note: These are not connected through the root vue instance.**

I have tried the following but not worked,

Component1:

```
mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('Component1', () => {
        // your code goes here
        this.windowResize()
    }
}
```

Component2:

```
...
doResize(){
 this.$root.$emit('component1') //like this
},
```

Kindly help me to figure out this.

Comment: For a start you emit component1 and listen for Component1. Can you see they are different

Answer (score 2):

```js
methods: {
  dispatchWindowResize() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))
  }
}
```

Calling `this.dispatchWindowResize()` inside that component will dispatch a new [`window.resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) event on window object, which will run all listeners added to it from any source, including the ones added by other components in your app.

**Documentation:**

- [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)
- [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

Test:

```js
const Emitter = Vue.defineComponent({
  template: '#emitter-template',
  methods: {
    dispatchWindowResize() {
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))
    }
  }
})
const Receiver = Vue.defineComponent({
  template: '<div></div>',
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.logResize)
  },
  methods: {
    logResize() {
      console.log(`window.resize: {w: ${window.innerWidth}, h: ${window.innerHeight}}`);
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.logResize)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Emitter, Receiver }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://v2.vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <receiver></receiver>
  <emitter></emitter>
</div>
<template id="emitter-template">
  <button @click="dispatchWindowResize">Dispath window resize</button>
</template>
```

`<Receiver />` receives all resize events: the ones triggered by resizing the browser window and the ones triggered by clicking the button inside `<Emitter />`